# Add FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT between different owners

Tags: oracle-xe

I'm logged on a Oracle XE instance as SYSTEM user. When I try to run an script that create users, tables and constraints I get an `ORA-01031` error. The script is as follows:

```sql
CREATE USER AA IDENTIFIED BY AA DEFAULT TABLESPACE users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
CREATE USER BB IDENTIFIED BY BB DEFAULT TABLESPACE users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO AA WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO BB WITH ADMIN OPTION;
...
CREATE TABLE ...
CREATE INDEX ...
...
ALTER TABLE "BB"."B_TABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_BB_AA" FOREIGN KEY ("AA_ID")
  REFERENCES "AA"."A_TABLE" ("ID") ENABLE; -- this line report the error
```

It's not possible to to add this constraint on Oracle XE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there should never be a situation where you are granting `ALL PRIVILEGES` to a user and particularly not `WITH ADMIN OPTION`.  That is just a poor way to manage security.  In anything approximating a real system, you would want to determine what privileges are actually needed and grant only those privileges.

Second, in order for a foreign key in schema `BB` to reference a parent table in `AA`, `BB` must have the `REFERENCE` privilege on the parent table in `AA`.  Since there is no `REFERENCE ANY TABLE` system privilege, you would need to grant `BB` the `REFERENCE` privilege on `AA.A_TABLE` after creating the table but before creating the foreign key.

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON aa.a_table TO bb;
```

Comment: this is not the real database, I'm using Oracle XE to do Integration Tests of my application, I do not have dba privileges on the real database server. And I do not have only this two user, I have 11 users and about 70 tables. I'll have to run this command to all tables and users or there is a easier way?

Comment: You would need to run the statement for every object for every user that you want to be able to create a child table of that object.  It would seem very, very odd to have 11 users each of which create child tables based on 70 different parent tables-- if you have more than a handful of these cross-schema foreign keys, it is likely that the approach to identifying what schemas you need is problematic.  That said, you could write a bit of dynamic SQL that would generate and execute all 770 combinations of this stateement.

Comment: I just did that. Created the dynamic SQL to generate the combinations. Thanks for the tip.